# Which weapon counts as "first" towards Ultimate Pro achievement?

Tags: achievements, nioh

The Ultimate Pro achievement description reads as

> Reached maximum proficiency with your first weapon.

Which weapon should actually be counted as *first*? Is it the straight sword you get in the prison during the prologue mission? Or is it the first weapon of your choice that you obtain in Japan?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the discussion [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/181161-nioh/74957432), it looks like the trophy is poorly worded. It seems that the unlock is actually from maxing out your first weapon *type*, which is at 999999/999999. You can actually choose any weapon type for this; it doesn't have to be the one you started with. By "first", it means the first one you max, not the first one you pick up.

> You need to max the proficiency of a weapon type, not a single weapon. Go to status and on additional stats you will see your proficiency with every weapon type. Get one of them to 999999 to unlock the trophy.

This is also supported in [PowerPyx's trophy guide](http://www.powerpyx.com/nioh-trophy-guide-roadmap/):

> The maximum profiency score is “999,999”. Your procifiency increases every time you hurt an enemy. Even if your weapon’s proficiency is at maximum (e.g. 900/900) it will keep counting additional proficiency points in the background. So you do not have to switch weapons after one is maxed out. If you stick to a single weapon type you should unlock this at about 50% campaign completion. Just stick to one weapon type and it’ll come automatically on your playthrough.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is poorly worded. It's just open to interpretation if you are reading it as a hint on how to get the achievement, not about what the achievement is. It is the achievement for reaching max proficiency with a weapon the first time.

Comment: @CyberClaw true, but "open to interpretation" isn't a great attribute for the description of a trophy, which is what most players use to figure out what they need to do to get it.

Comment: @CyberClaw this question appeared exactly because description is "open to interpretation".

Comment: I think one point of clarity will help everyone.  "Familiarity" is how much you have used a specific weapon, whereas "proficiency" goes with the weapon categories.  You gain proficiency separately for katana, dual katana, spear, axe, and kusarigama.  Familiarity gives bonuses on a specific weapon's stats and having maximum familiarity with a weapon allows its inheritable abilities to be passed onto a new weapon with "Soul Matching".  Proficiency gives small improvements to a weapon class as well as opening up their respective "Mystic Arts" at maximum proficiency.